# Group by with two columns

Tags: sql, mysqli, group-by

I am trying to write a query using group by in sub query ,I referred lot of blogs but could not get all the values.

I have three tables and below is the structure of those tables.

Pet_Seller_Master

```
ps_id   ps_name city_id                         
2       abc     1                               
3       xyz     2                               
4       fer     4                               
5       bbb     1
```

City_Master

```
city_id city_name     
1       Bangalore    
2       COIMBATORE   
4       MYSORE
```

Api_Entry

```
api_id   ps_id otp
1        2     yes
2        3  
3        2     yes
4        3     yes
5        4           
6        5     yes
7        5     yes      
8        5     yes
```

Query is to get number of sellers, no of pet sellers with zero otp, no of pet sellers  with 1 otp, no of pet sellers  with 2 otp,no of pet sellers  with  otp>2 for the particular city and within date range.

Through Below query I am able to get city , psp , and zero otp

```
select cm.city_name,
     count(ps.ps_id) as PSP,
     ((select count(ps1.ps_id) 
          FROM ps_master ps1  
          WHERE ps1.city = cm.city_id)-
       (SELECT count(distinct ps1.ps_id) 
          from ps_master ps1  
          INNER JOIN api_entry ae ON ps1.ps_id = ae.ps_id  and otp!=''
          WHERE ps1.city = cm.city_id  and date(timestamp) >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND date(timestamp) < curdate())) as zero_psp 
  from ps_master ps INNER JOIN city_master cm ON ps.city = cm.city_id and                    cm.city_type = 'IN HOUSE PNS'
   group by city_id
```

Please tell me the solution to solve this query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please some one help me to solve this . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to do and you were on a right track. Here is what I would use:

```
select c.city_name, a.otp, p.ps_name, COUNT(*) nbr
from Api_Entry a
inner join Pet_Seller_Master p on p.ps_id=a.ps_id
inner join City_Master c on p.city_id=c.city_id
group by c.city_name, a.otp, p.ps_name
```

Now, if you want to get the number of sellers with zero otp, you just apply `where` clause:

```
where otp <> 'yes'
```

If you want to get the number of pet sellers with otp>2, then you just use subquery:

```
select * 
from (
    select c.city_name, a.otp, p.ps_name, COUNT(*) nbr
    from #tempA a
    inner join #tempP p on p.ps_id=a.ps_id
    inner join #tempC c on p.city_id=c.city_id
    group by c.city_name, a.otp, p.ps_name
) g
where nbr > 2
```